# cannot run any npm global command

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, create-react-app

I cannot run any of my npm global commands.

The root of my global files are at `/Users/Alex/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules`. I obtained this from running `npm -g root`

I am trying to run `create-react-app <filename>`. Create React App is located at `/Users/Alex/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/create-react-app`. I can run `node createReactApp.js` from this directory and spawn a project, however this is very inconvenient.

When I run `create-react-app` in shell I get `zsh: command not found: create-react-app`. So I decided to modify my `.bash_profile`. Currently it looks like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

# NPM
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin/:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules:$PATH"

#Create Reac App
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/create-react-app:$PATH"
```

and I still cannot run any of my npm global commands.

How can I run my npm global commands like `create-react-app <filename>`? I've been scratching my head for about 40 minutes trying different things, reading various blogs, and numerous github tickets, various stack overflow questions and I still cannot solve this npm problem.

**UPDATE**

I've included the following to my `.bash_profile` and then ran `source .bash_profile` to update my `$PATH`

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export PATH
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:"$PATH"
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:"$PATH"
...
```

Now my global commands work.

Comment: The command you are trying to invoke is supposed to be in the `bin` folder, not `lib`. What happens if you type `$ which create-react-app` ?

Comment: @andyaldoo I get `create-react-app not found`. Which makes no sense. I have installed it successfully....

Comment: @andyaldoo i have also modified the create-react-app path to be `export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin/create-react-app:$PATH"` and I still get the error `create-react-app command not found`.

Comment: If you echo your $PATH, does it include `/Users/Alex/.npm-packages/bin`? if it does, go to the folder and see if all your npm commands are there and check if the symlinks are pointing to the correct library.

Comment: @andyaldoo My `$PATH` does not include `/Users/Alex/.npm-packages/bin`. Is there a way to reset this variable to what is in my `.bash_profile`? I think this might be a solution...

Comment: Have you looked into the folder and see if the global npm commands are there? You can just include `/Users/Alex/.npm-packages/bin` to your $PATH and it should solve the problem. I personally don't have any experience resetting the $PATH. Refer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/121870/how-do-i-reset-the-path-variable-on-mac-os-x) for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the folder and see if the global npm commands are there? If it does, you can just include `/Users/Alex/.npm-packages/bin` to your $PATH and it should solve the problem. Otherwise, there is a possibility that you have installed the global packages incorrectly. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my question with some extra steps. I hope someone else who stumbles across this will read your excellent problem solving skills. Thank you.